# ¿Cómo sumar valores de una columna de un JTable dinámico?

Tags: java, jtable

Buenas, tengo un `JTable` dinámico el cual contiene las columnas de producto, cantidad, precio, total. Lo que quiero es obtener la suma de la columna total para enviárselo a un `JTextField`, pero el problema es que yo agrego filas de acuerdo a mi necesidad y también modifico los valores de cantidad y precio, entonces los valores de la columna total no son fijos. Tengo la idea de hacer un ciclo de la siguiente forma:

```
float subtotal = 0; 
for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
    subtotal = (float) table.getValueAt(i, 3); //La columna 3 es la de total
}
```

Esto se ejecuta cada vez que hago un cambio en las columnas de cantidad y precio con un `TableModelListener` pero pienso que hacerlo con un ciclo no es lo más óptimo, debido a que si tengo muchas filas, el ciclo tendrá que recorrer más y además se ejecutará el ciclo siempre que modifique las celdas. ¿Alguna idea para mejorarlo? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: La respuesta que hay es bastante razonable, pero falta la pregunta previa: ¿Es realmente necesario? Sumar números que ya están en memoria es una cosa bastante rápida; a no ser que tengas muchísimos números es improbable que ningún usuario note esa mejora. Y las optimizaciones suelen acarrear costes de a) tiempo de implementación b) complejidad del código (bugs, mayor dificultad de mantenimiento) e incluso, en ocasiones, c) ser más lentas en casos particulares. Antes de ponerse a optimizar el rendimiento conviene averiguar si merece la pena.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay muchas maneras de hacer esto. Particularmente creo que tienes dos lineas de acción:

- Crear tu propio [TableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) Lo mas fácil para esto quizás sea heredar de [DefaultTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) o cualquiera de sus implemtaciones. Con un modelado inteligente y el uso del método `fireTableCellUpdated` estoy seguro de que obtendrás buenos resultados. Dentro del modelo puedes contralar que celda ha sido actualizada y recalcular el subtotal restando el total actual y sumando el anterior. Te dejo un ejemplo simple para que veas a lo que me refiero:

  ```
  public class MyAbstractTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
  ```

  ```
  private static final int TOTAL_COLUM = 2;
  private static final int PRICE_COLUM = 1;
  private static final int COUNT_COLUM = 0;
  int subtotal = 0;

  public MyAbstractTableModel(Object[][] data, Object[] columnNames) {
      super(data, columnNames);
  }

  @Override
  public void fireTableCellUpdated(int row, int column) {
      super.fireTableCellUpdated(row, column);

      // si han actualizado la cantidad o el precio
      if (column == 0 || column == 1) {
          final Integer actualTotalValue = getIntegerValue(row, TOTAL_COLUM);
          final Integer newTotalValue = 
                  getIntegerValue(row, COUNT_COLUM) 
                  * getIntegerValue(row, PRICE_COLUM);

          subtotal = subtotal - actualTotalValue + newTotalValue;
          this.setValueAt(newTotalValue, row, TOTAL_COLUM);
      }
  }

  private Integer getIntegerValue(int row, int column) {
      return (Integer) this.getValueAt(row, column);
  }

  @Override
  public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
      super.setValueAt(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(aValue)), row, column);
  }
  ```

  }
- Otra posible idea es usar java.util.Observer como elementos de la tabla. De esta manera puedes implementar un sistema de eventos que mantenga todo actualizado.

Comment: Muchas gracias! La verdad me parece muy factible el restar el valor total antes de modificarlo, así evito que recorra todo el tiempo todas las filas de la columna total!